# how to us external api in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have created react app using the npm module 'create-react-app'

I wanted to use external API for say `api.example.com` but was unable to call the **external API because axios is requesting localhost rather** than external API.

I tried the following Code:

```
class Example extends Component{
   static defaultProps={
      'url':"api.example.com"
   }
  handleChange(event){
      axios.get(this.props.url+event.target.value)
      .then(result=> console.log(result.data)
     }
   }
 }
```

How to allow react app to access external API?

Comment: Try adding a protocol to begin with. `https://api.example.com`

Comment: can you please explain it more @YuryTarabanko

Comment: Something like this: `axios.get('https://api.example.com/'+event.target.value)`.

Comment: If you don't specify an absolute url, the request will use the same host as your window.location. Maybe something like `http://localhost:3000`, and then add the partial url to add up to something like this: `http://localhost:3000/api.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

**For example, POST request for added some Product in database:**

In example I use JWT authentification for access at API.

*`JSON.stringify` not necessary use, because Axios already implement this feature, here it is used for greater understanding. Don't use this on production!*

```
const jwtToken = 'd70414362252a41ceger5re435gdgd45hjk';
const data = JSON.stringify({
  id: '5',
  title: 'product'
  price: '15000',
  description: 'string',
});

const configAxios = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer + ${jwtToken}`,
  },
};

axios.post('https://api.somesite.com/products', data, configAxios)
.then((res) => {
  this.date.description = res.data;
  console.log(res);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.warn('error during http call', err);
});
```

*It's also important to note that we strictly write the JWT token in the code, although it must be received periodically, this is not realized in this example.*